# reading from ADC which pins to use

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BXX4UWC) analog to digital converter to my raspberry pi (version b+) but everything I have read seems to use different pins from what I assumed based on [this](http://pi.gadgetoid.com/pinout/i2c) pinout website. Can someone tell me which pins (in GPIO.BOARD style) to use? A simple example of the python code to read from the adc would also be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ADC communicates over I2C. The RPi B+ can use SMBUS in python (like in the link you have in your question) to communicate over I2C. I imagine that 2 of the lines on this ADC are V+ and GND, the other two will correspond with the SCL (clock line for I2C) and the SDA (data line for I2C) which on the B+ are physical pins 3 (SDA) and 5(SCL).

**Edit 1:**

Once you have it connected you'll need the address of the ADC. You can get it with

`i2cdetect -y 1`

at the shell.

For some example code check out [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-I2C-Python/step5/Example-1-CMPS03-Compass-Module/).